# Twilio - Making a call from .NET Windows application to a Phone

Tags: c#, .net, twilio, windows, twilio-twiml

I am trying to write a windows application to call a phone number(Twilio verified) from my application directly.
What i was able to achieve was:
- To call a phone number and read out a voice sms as mentioned in the [TWIML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml) url.
- to call a phone number and then redirect it to another phone number ( by using  in the TwiML).

But what i want to do now is:
- Call a phone number directly from the application using my Headphones attached to the pc where the app is running. Is there a way to do that?

Please let me know if my question is not clear enough and i should to try to explain it in more detailed format.

Thanks!!!

Comment: This is the code i added to client side:I have this in my client code:     string AccountSid = "As in my trial acc";
           string AuthToken = "As in my trial acc";
           var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);
            var options = new CallOptions();
            options.Url = "myURL.xml"; // in this xml i have another number with <Dial> tag.
            options.To = "My Twilio verified number";
            options.From = "My Twilio verified number";

Comment: So, basically i am able to call from one mobile to another using this method but what i actually want to achieve is to make a call directly from my .NET client application. (similar to the Browser to Phone article http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-client/can-i-make-calls-from-a-phone-to-a-web-browser) But i want to do it from my .NET application and not the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Unfortunately today we don't offer a native Windows version of Twilio Client, which it what sounds like you are looking for.

The only suggestion I have is to use the .NET browser control to embed a browser into your application.  I have not tried this, so I don't know what if any problems you'll have.

Devin

Comment: Nothing for Windows? Maybe I'm in luck, I just switched over to Linux the other week. You have anything for Linux (Ubuntu)?

Comment: @tommmy: nothing for native apps on linux either.  Twilio Client has SDK's for iOS, Android and Javascript. We have added the ability use Twilio as a SIP endpoint so you could possible write a VoIP client that leverages that.

Comment: If Twilio provides JavaScript library for that purpose. I think https://electron.atom.io/ is a great framework for desktop application through this I believe, it will serve the purpose.