# Developing a Delphi Windows application using Twilio VoIP

Tags: windows, twilio

I would like to integrate Twilio VoIP capabilities in a Windows application developed in Delphi.

From this post [Twilio - Making a call from .NET Windows application to a Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141981/twilio-making-a-call-from-net-windows-application-to-a-phone) it seems this is not viable directly. Is it still the case or there are further implementation for this ?